# Creating a histogram with angular and d3.js

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I am new to angular and d3.js, not sure how to create an histogram using these tech-stack.

I tried using the default documentation way but it is failing by giving the error **Property 'price' does not exist on type 'number'**. can anyone help on this ?

sample code snippet is provided below

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-histogram',
  templateUrl: './histogram.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./histogram.component.css']
})
// export type DataType = { x: any, y: any };
export class HistogramComponent implements OnInit {

  private svg: d3.Selection<SVGGElement, unknown, HTMLElement, any>;
  private margin = 50;
  private width = 750 - (this.margin * 2);
  private height = 400 - (this.margin * 2);

  constructor() { }

  private createSvg(): void {
    this.svg = d3.select('figure#histogram')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', this.width + (this.margin * 2))
      .attr('height', this.height + (this.margin * 2))
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin + ',' + this.margin + ')');
  }

  private drawBars(data: any[]): void {
    console.log(data);
    // Create the X-axis band scale
    const x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([0, this.width])
      .domain([0, 1000]);


    // Draw the X-axis on the DOM
    this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.height + ')')
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.height + ')');

    // set the parameters for the histogram
    const dom = x.domain();
    const histogram = d3.histogram()
      .value(d => d.price)   // I need to give the vector of value
      .domain([dom[0], dom[1]])  // then the domain of the graphic
      .thresholds(x.ticks(70)); // then the numbers of bins

    // And apply this function to data to get the bins
    const bins = histogram(data);

    // Create the Y-axis band scale
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(bins, d => d.length)])
      .range([this.height, 0]);

    // append the bar rectangles to the svg element
    this.svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(bins)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', 1)
      .attr('transform', (d: { x0: number | { valueOf(): number; }; length: number | { valueOf(): number; }; }) => 'translate(' + x(d.x0) + ',' + y(d.length) + ')')
      .attr('width', (d: { x1: number | { valueOf(): number; }; x0: number | { valueOf(): number; }; }) => Math.abs(x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) - 1))
      .attr('height', (d: string | any[]) => this.height - y(d.length))
      .style('fill', 'grey');

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createSvg();
    // this.drawBars(this.data);
    d3.csv('/assets/histogram.csv').then(data => this.drawBars(data));
  }

}
```

Below is the link for the official docs which I used:
**https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/histogram_basic.html**

[input object for the reference][1]
[1]: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/R75Nq.png**

Comment: what does your data look like during the console log  in drawBars?

Comment: its a javascript array of objects for your reference have attached the image link

Comment: Worth checking if the attributes in the object include an attribute called "price" ? The object shown in the screenshot will need to be expanded to see the attributes

Comment: Yes the array contains the objects which has price attribute updated the image for more clarity

Comment: my guess is that the price is coming as string. Try  .value(d =>{  console.log('price',d.price); return parseInt(d.price);  }); if it still doesnt work then might be worth putting jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks man actually, the value of price was coming the issue was with Y axis which got resolved. Thanks a lot :-) and regarding this error then I was trying to access the property of the object while the price is an element.